# Django Rest deployment on CPanel

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cpanel, django-staticfiles

I am working on Django Rest project and it's admin side is working fine and properly loading with their static files on local sever. I tried to deploy my project on CPanel where I setup my python setup application successfully but when I load Django admin side with live url link it only shows textfields without classes applied.

[image: Django-admin]

Live django endpoint from where django admin tries to load static files is like this:

```
https://example.com/api/static/admin/css/base.css
```

Where ***api*** is the Application url of my Python app that I setup on CPanel.

I also ran this command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

but still server is not able to locate the files.

Comment: Hmmm… can't reach this page

Comment: can you share the settings of static in settings.py ??

Comment: STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Comment: Share your project folder structure too.

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps:

- Step:1

```py
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']  # comment this
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static' # Add this
```

- Step:2

run command `python manage.py collectstatic`

- Step:3

Reload app

Comment: i did the same procedure but the issue remains same as to get base.css file for admin side it still hitting the same URL (https://example.com/api/static/admin/css/base.css) and getting 404.
"https://example.com/api/" this URL Is the backend URL for our python django app deployed on cpanel.